# Why is my CNN model overfitting, and does anyone have tips for better results?

Tags: validation, machine-learning

I am training a CNN-multichannel model with dropout and weight constraint for the dense layer. I am using two inputs, as I am trying to classify a document using its title and abstract. Furthermore, I am training on an oversampled dataset, as the original dataset is imbalanced. The original dataset has about 3700 samples, where 2% is positive. I am using a dropout of 0.7, 100 filters, and conv kernels of 3, 4, and 5.

[image: Model]

The image below is my loss. The green line is the training loss, and the grey line is the validation loss.  Can anyone explain why my validation loss is first increasing, and why the two lines do not come together? Furthermore, does anyone have tips for getting better results?

[image: Model loss]

**EDIT:** If I lower or remove the dropout after the embedding layers, the validation loss does converge. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Try to refer to these 2 websites:

1. [How to Reduce Overfitting With Dropout Regularization in Keras](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-reduce-overfitting-with-dropout-regularization-in-keras/)
2. [How to Reduce Overfitting Using Weight Constraints in Keras](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-reduce-overfitting-in-deep-neural-networks-with-weight-constraints-in-keras/)

Comment: I have used these websites as well, but I cannot explain why my validation loss goes up first, and why they do not converge. If I lower or remove the dropout after the embedding layers, the validation loss does converge. Why is this happening?

Comment: Always validation loss rise problem arises when there is no correct distribution od train-test split. so please make sure to train with 60-40, 70-30 split, and then 80-20 split which will help to gradually get good training with lowering of loss.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But for the paper I am comparing to, we are using a 40-10-50 train-val-test split, as this is more suitable for the real-life situation (splitting the dataset in half). Could that be the reason?